# How do you check if environment variables are defined in windows batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I am trying to create a batch file to check if the environment variables are defined or undefined and gives a certain output statement if it is or not. This is what I have and I can't seem to get the program to tell me that any argument is defined.

```
if not defined "%MyVar%" (
    echo MyVar is NOT defined
)

if defined "%MyVar%" (
    echo MyVar IS defined 
)
```

Comment: What relevance does `%MyVar%` have to `%1`?

Comment: @Compo The MyVar variable is supposed to be an "environment variable" and when you run the program in cmd.exe and type the filename with and argument the %1 refers to the argument.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you mean to write:

```
if not defined MyVar (
  echo MyVar is NOT defined
)
```

and

```
if defined MyVar (
  echo MyVar IS defined 
)
```

This is because cmd.exe will expand the reference to the *content* of the variable if you enclose it within `%` characters. (You want to know if the variable *itself* is defined, not if a variable with the name of the *content* of that variable is defined.)

Note that *environment variables* (names within `%` characters) are different from *replaceable parameters* (`%0`, `%1`, etc.).

I would recommend switching to Windows PowerShell, because it has built-in parameter parsing features, variable scopes, real functions, and much, much more.

Comment: So I changed it to MyVar without the % signs. Do I have to point the program to look at a specific path to look at the environment variables?

Comment: If you want cmd.exe to _evaluate_ the variable, you must enclose it in `%` characters.

Comment: What is wrong with `If Not Defined %1 (Echo=%1 is not defined) Else Echo=%1 is defined` then?

Comment: `%1` is a replaceable parameter, not an environment variable.